# What is the actual probability?

Tags: percentages

So here’s the scenario. In Madden Mobile you have what’s called % counters to either run, long pass, short pass or pa pass. So say I have a 2% chance of countering a run play. It takes my opponent 15 plays to score a td, only using one run play out of the 15 plays and being countered once on a run play. What is the actually % chance of being countered on a run in that scenario? I have a 2% run counter yet it counters him on the only run play he chose?

Comment: Rare events still occur.

Comment: Maybe this was one of the two out of a hundred. One would need to study a large number of plays to determine if this parameter has changed.